# RequestComAddInAutomationService is not being called in VSTO Outlook addin

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I have an application level Outlook 2010 VSTO addin and have overriden the [RequestComAddInAutomationService](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.addinbase.requestcomaddinautomationservice%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function. On two development PCs (1 with Outlook 2007 and one with Outlook 2010) I have tested the code with Visual Studio 2012 and the function is called.

```
Protected Overrides Function RequestComAddInAutomationService() As Object

    MsgBox("Request being Made")

    If dbShortCutCtrl Is Nothing Then
        dbShortCutCtrl = New DBShortCutKeyController
    End If

    Return dbShortCutCtrl
End Function
```

The problem is when I deploy the addin this function is not called. The addin functions as expected it is just this function is not called.

What could the reason be that this function is not called when VSTO starts up with Outlook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the Class DBShortCutKeyController is not being registered for COM properly and thus this function is not being called.